# Assign a new random direction to data member that is different from the current in c++

Tags: c++, class, random, assign, non-repetitive

```
class Child:public Parent{
public:
    enum Direction { Left, Right, Up, Down };
    Direction direction;
    void Update();            
private:
    int x,y;
    void ChangeDirection();
    void Draw();
```

};

I need the **Update()** function which invokes **ChangeDirection()** and **Draw()** to increment and decrements the **x y** values upon current direction which i have done. My problem is that **y**  or **x** cannot be (-)value.

And also **ChangeDirection()** should assign a random direction to direction data and again this direction must be **different to current direction.**
I was able to **cout** random directions within the same **ChangeDirection()** function this way

```
Direction direction = static_cast<Direction>(rand() % 4);
cout << direction;
```

but again sometime it prints the same direction. Now what i want is, the random assignment to direction should occur in **ChangeDirection()** member function not allowing the current value again but it should display the results through the **void Draw();** member function which increments or decrements the **x y** values without letting it to be (-)value (should be clamped to 0).
this is what i have done for that.

```
if ( direction == 0 ){
    cout << "Right";
    x++;
}
else if (direction == 1 ){
    cout << "Down";
    y++;
}
else if (direction == 2 ){
    cout << "Up";
    y--;
}
else if (direction == 3 ){
    cout << "Left";
    x--;
}
Draw();
```

But it is giving (-)values. how do I step forward
..

Comment: Since you're not giving any restriction on x and y, so they obviously can take any value.

Comment: but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning a random direction, it makes sense that the direction which is assigned sometimes is equal to the previous direction. Try something like:

```
Direction direction = static_cast<Direction>((currentDirection + 1 + (rand() % 3) ) % 4);
```

to ensure that you get a new direction

Edit:
To answer the other part of your question, you must check the value of x and y prior to incrementing or decrementing to ensure that they are within the bounds of whatever you are currently using. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
 if(x > 0){
   x--;
 } else {
 //do something else
 }
```

Comment: That really helped, condition statement for x and y.. but assigning random direction still prints similar at times. I think that also should have a condition to assign direction again if similar occurs....    have any idea how to make it..?

Comment: Ohhh woops. I forgot that rand() can return 0. I have editted my post above to have the correct way to ensure a new value.

Comment: excellent!! it works fine now. Still if i invoke 20 times i find it to be similar in two or three places.. it's ok since i want it only 5 times. Anyway if you get any idea to filter through a loop or something, so that we can assign again till we get different one, then let me know please.